# How to change Airflow's tmp data directory?

Tags: airflow

I'm currently running some disk-hungry tasks in Airflow 1.10.5, which are adding some large files (i.e. `tmpnhre0_s8.__wz_cache`) to the `/tmp` directory. As the root partition `/` is almost full, I would like to make Airflow use different directory, that lives in a larger partition, to store those temporary files.

How can I configure Airflow to use a different directory for the temporary files?

Answer (score -1):

Same here, I'd like switch cache to redis backend. But it is still hardcoded https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/www/app.py#L122

You can monkey patch it or, fork and contribute to the airflow.